# How to change django-filter filtering key?

Tags: python, django-2.1

I've tried this way

```
class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    section = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(widget=CustomLinkWidget, queryset=Category.objects.filter(parent=None),
                                               label='Раздел', field_name='subcategory__parent__parent__slug')
```

Unfortunately filter keep doing this

```
http://localhost:8000/products/mediasabak-sub/mediasabak-sub-sub/?section=1
```

But i wanna something like this

```
http://localhost:8000/products/mediasabak-sub/mediasabak-sub-sub/?section=section_slug_here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fild_name = 'foreign_key_field_name__slug'
to_field_name = 'slug'
```

this two keyword arguments are important.

`to_field_name` doesn't work without `field_name` and
`field_name` doesn't work without `to_field_name`